# What will create a box with largest volume?given image

Tags: quadratics, word-problem

Jamal wants to make a box with no top out of a $24$ $inch^2$ piece of cardboard. She plans to cut smaller squares of equal size from the corners of the cardboard and fold up the resulting sides. 
By rounding to the nearest inch, what size of the square cut outs will create a box with the largest volume? 
I was thinking of using calculator, but I don't think that will work
How do I solve this?

[image]

So the things i got are that the length

L=24-x or is 24-2x?
To find a volume you do l*w*h
But i dont think i did it right

Sorry for not editing the post nicely im doing this in my phone

Comment: The bottom of the box will be a square which is $24-2x$ by $24-2x$. The volume will be $x(24-2x)^2$.

Comment: The bottom of the square? Like the length and width and x is the hieght? So how would i find the maximum

Comment: Yes, the length of the bottom is $24-2x$ and the width is $24-2x$. The height of the box is $x$. The volume is $x(24-2x)^2$, as I wrote earlier. We want to maximize $x(24-2x)^2$, with the constraint that $0\le x\le 12$. The standard way to maximize is to use the derivative. There are also non-calculus approaches, but calculus is simplest.

Comment: Isnt (24-x)(24-x) gonna be 576-24x-24x+x^2

Comment: I would like to solve it with the calculator if possible

Comment: Yes i got that but when i tried using the calculator to graph, i could graph it though the maximum i got was 7.9 but it was supposed to 4

Comment: I got a curved line when i plugged it in the calculator to graph it

Comment: You can look at the curve (between $x=0$ and $x=12$) and see at what $x$ the curve is highest.

Comment: It was at 8, but the correct answer is supposed to be 4? I was having trouble at that

Comment: My fault, I did not check your multiplication. Recall that the volume is $x(24-2x)^2$. Maybe your calculator will graph that, without expansion, But if you expand you should get $576x-96x^2+4x^3$.

Comment: Oh so i guess it was my multiplication problem

Comment: That may have been the problem. Your calculator would probably have been perfectly happy to graph $x(24-2x)^2$, so the multiplication was probably unnecessary. But I think the real problem was that you were continuing to work with $x(24-x)^2$ instead of the $x(24-2x)^2$ of my first comment.

Comment: How would it be $$(24 - 2x)^2$$ $$(24-x)(24-x)$$ The x would just turn into squares right? how did you get 2x^2

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, Please forget your $24-x$, it is wrong. The base of the box is a $24-2x$ by $24-2x$ square, the height is $x$, so the volume is $x(24-2x)^2$. If you want to expand $(24-2x)^2$ (there is probably no need to do so) write $(24-2x)(24-2x)$ and multiply out. Or take a factor of $2$ from each, we get $4(12-x)(12-x)$, which makes for easier arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine cutting out the four little squares and folding the four flaps upward. Then we create a box whose bottom is a $24-2x$ by $24-2x$ square.

The volume of the box is then $x(24-2x)^2$. Note that we must have $0\lt x\lt 12$.

We want to maximize $x(24-2x)^2$, where $x$ ranges over the interval $(0,12)$. The standard technique for this uses the calculus. But you are asking for a procedure that uses a calculator, presumably a graphing calculator. Have the machine graph $x(24-2x)^2$ (over the interval $0\lt x\lt 12$). You should be able to see for what $x$ in this interval the function attains a maximum.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering, I forgot that it was (24-2x), so basically all i have to do is L*W*H and that would give me the equation to maximize?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, and as I mentioned earlier it is not worthwhile to expand $x(24-2x)^2$. Your calculator will be perfectly happy to graph it without you going to the trouble of expanding. Saves a lot of time, and minimizes the probability of an arithmetical slipup. The answer by the way is that the maximum is reached at exactly $x=4$. (I do not have a graphing calculator, so used calculus.)

Comment: I hope you can see from your picture why it is $24-2x$ rather than $24-x$. We are removing a strip of width $x$ from **both** ends. So the side of the "inner" square in your picture is $24-2x$.

Comment: Yes, I understood that thank you for answering my question